# Flutter) I want to automatically reconnect when the socket is disconnected

Tags: flutter, sockets, websocket

I am building a Flutter app. Socket communication is implemented with the 'web_socket_channel' package. I want to implement the two functions below.

- Socket **disconnection detection**
- **Automatic reconnection** attempt when socket disconnection is detected

Unfortunately, the 'web_socket_channel' package does not provide these functions.
Can you give me some advice on how to implement it?

Comment: There is no such thing as reconnecting a TCP socket. You have to close it and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two streams, one of them will be reconnecting to the socket in case of disruptions, and the other will be used by outside classes to have a constant connection. Data from the first stream is transferred to the second one.

Here is a detailed explanation with a code example: https://medium.com/@ilia_zadiabin/websocket-reconnection-in-flutter-35bb7ff50d0d

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this

```
    createSocket(){
          IOWebSocketChannel channel;
          try {
            channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://...');
            channel.stream.listen((data) async {
              //Do something here
            }).onDone(() {
              print("Socket Done");
              createSocket();
            });
          } catch (ex) {
            print("SOCKET ERROR");
            print(ex);
            createSocket();
          }
     }
```

Comment: Don't use recursion as a form of iteration.

Comment: @user207421 But how is it possible to do it without recursion?